# something is restarting crond! How do I stop this?

Tags: ssh, cron

I believe something is trying to get into my system, and also that something already has and there is a process that is rewriting my databases.  I have turned mail OFF for now and that seems to have stuck as there is no log of mail going out.

Here is from my last login at 10:39:05 UTC:

```
ssh root@xxx.com
root@xxx.com's password:
Last failed login: Sun Aug 14 10:31:45 UTC 2016 [8 minutes prior] from 116.31.116.18 on ssh:notty
There were 222 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
Last login: Sun Aug 14 04:11:35 2016 [previous evening, this was me] from 123.456.789.012 (my IP)
```

I am the only person who uses the server.  Also, `116.31.116.18` is an IP address out of Australia based on http://whois.urih.com/record/116.31.116.18/

Last night I did this:

```
service crond stop
```

And it said that crond was inactive, but now this morning it says it is active again.

How do I uninstall cron completely?  That would be the safe option for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet does not show that anyone got into your system, only that there were attempts.  This is, unfortunately, perfectly normal.  *Any* machine visible on the internet with TCP/22 open will get numerous login attempts.  You can reduce the chances of any of them being successful by

- not allowing root login.  Use (or create) a normal user for connecting, and add (or modify) the line `PermitRootLogin no` in your `sshd_config`.
- not using passwords.  Setup publickey authentication for *any* system that is publicly visible, and disallow all password attempts with the configuration item `PasswordAuthentication no`.
- specify which users (presumably only you) may login in with the `AllowUsers` directive (or, for a more complicated setup, an appropriate combination of `DenyUsers`, `AllowUsers`, `DenyGroups`, and `AllowGroups`).

---

As for cron, how you stop it will depend on which flavour of linux and which flavour of `crond` you are using.  To disable the daemon (rather than individual users' crontabs), you might try something like

```
service cron stop
```

or

```
systemctl stop cron
```

If it respawns after you have stopped it, check that `/etc/inittab` does not have a `respawn` entry for the daemon.

Comment: ++ for the /etc/inittab comment @user4556274.  However `nano /etc/inittab` shows everything`#` commented out, and the first line is `inittab is no longer used when using systemd.`  Just FYI

Comment: @OliverWilliams, right, so the systemd equivalent would be `Restart=on-failure` in `crond.service`

Answer (score -1):

You can remove crond with:

> crontab -r

```
The current crontab will be removed.
```

[crontab(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab)

`Current crontab` means the current user, you can use `whoami` and check your user.

Comment: when you say the `current crontab`, what does that mean?  Is that the crontab of the current user (i.e. `whoami`)?  Is there any way to list all crontabs which have jobs (i.e. non-empty)

Comment: You can list it with `crontab -l -u <user>`.  Current crontab means the corrent user, yes. I edited my answer.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. `crontab -r` removes crontab entries, but it doesn't prevent crond itself from running.